# dbDisconnect() dont close session in R

Tags: r, rpostgresql

I have such problem:
I cant close my session using dbDisconnect()

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, 
                 dbname = "dbname",
                 user = "user",
                 password = "password",
                 host = "host",
                 port = "port" )

dbListConnections(drv)
```

result:

> ```
> [[1]]
> <PostgreSQLConnection:(9174,0)>
> ```

Then i want to close this connection

```
dbDisconnect(con)
[1] True
dbUnloadDriver(drv)
[1] True
```

After dbDisconnect() and dbUnloadDriver() my objects **con** and **drv** become expired PostgreSQLConnection and expired PostgreSQLDriver.

But my database administrator says that this session is still running.
How can I fix it?

PS.
Also I tried to drop connection so: 
`dbDisconnect(dbListConnections(drv)[[1]])`

Comment: Edit that into the question instead of having it as a comment.